# How to use Data Contracts as Model for scaffolding in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have defined DataContracts in a different Library and I am referencing it in the MVC5 Application. In Visual Studio I want to use this Model and Generate Views using Scaffolding.

The Problem is when I click on Add View in the Action method inside Visual Studio 2013 I can see only Model defined in the MVC Application and not the entities in defined in Data Contracts.

How can I make a DataContracts appear in Model Dropdown in Visual Studio 2013 while adding View?

Comment: Couple of points to check, 1. .net version conflict in the referenced library, 2. Try to add view after building the project once

Comment: both are using .Net 4.5. Tried adding View after building the project as well.

Comment: Are you sure that the class is public